# How to understand "suivre des yeux" syntactically?

Tags: expressions, syntaxe

While reading *L'étranger* I found the following sentence:

> Quand elle était à la maison, maman passait son temps à me **suivre des yeux** en silence.

This is fairly easy to understand but I don't see how "suivre des yeux" works syntactically speaking. The expression means "follow [me] **with** her eyes (≈watch me)", not "follow her eyes", so why is it "suivre des yeux" and not "suivre avec ses yeux" or something of the sort? What is the syntactic role of "des yeux" here?

Also, what is "des"? An *article indéfini* or the contraction of *de + les*? My intuition is that it is the latter because when substituting "yeux" with "regard" one must say "suivre **du** regard". If so, what is the role of "de"?

Note: feel free to answer in either English or French.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*De* is indeed a preposition here. This usage isn't unique to *suivre*, but can appear whenever you want to say you did something with your eyes:

> Je l'ai vu de **mes propres yeux** (I saw it **with** my own two eyes)
>
> Je l'ai confirmé **de mes yeux** (I confirmed it **with** my eyes)
>
> Il m'a foudroyé **des** yeux (He glared at me, lit. He lightninged me **with** his eyes)

This isn't unique to the eyes either. There are a great many expressions in French that use *de* to mark the manner in which an action is done, the cause of the action of a reflexive verb or the agent of a passive verb. They are usually translated by *with* or *by* in English:

> Suivre **des** yeux (Follow **with** the eyes)
>
> Montrer **du** doigt (Show **with** a finger // **by** pointing a finger)
>
> Frapper **d**'un poing (Strike **with** a fist)
>
> Assomer **de** travail (overwork, lit. Stun **with** work)
>
> S'étrangler **de** rage (Choke **with** anger)
>
> S'éprendre **de** quelqu'un (Fall in love **with** someone)
>
> Être ivre **de** victoire (Be drunk **with** victory)
>
> Être aimé **de** tous (Be loved **by** all)

In Latin, those "*de*-noun phrases" would have been in the ablative case instead:

> **Oculis** abeuntia vela prosequi - Ovid ("He chases departing sails **with his eyes**")
>
> ...sed **digito** gulam ei monstrabat - [Visio Baronti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barontius_and_Desiderius) (some Late Latin for a change, dd. 678 or 679 CE) (...but **with his finger** he pointed at [the other man's] throat)
>
> Hic ita vixit, ut **universis Atheniensibus** merito esset carissimus - Cornelius Nepos' *Three Lives*, Atticus II 3 (Here he lived in such a manner that he was deservedly beloved **by every Athenian**)

Where *oculis*, *digitō*, and *universis Atheniensibus* are all in the ablative.

The ablative is named after a verb meaning "carry away **from**", but it had absorbed an earlier, separate case called the [instrumental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_case), used to mark the agent of a passive verb (*by*) or the object or mean used to accomplish an action (*with*).

The Latin ablative was replaced by *dē* in Vulgar Latin and its instrumental usages were ultimately inherited by *de* in Modern French.

In English (where the Instrumental had survived until Old English) these usages were taken over piecemeal by a variety of prepositions (*of* was used to mark passive agents in Middle English for example) until *by* and *with* won out.

*De* is concurrenced by *avec* and *par* for some of these instrumental uses, but it will nevertheless remain one of the main marker of *means* in the French language for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Wow, nice answer! Coincidentally, I was just about to ask a question on Linguistics.SE or Latin.SE about the usage of *de* in Latin to introduce the agent in passive constructions, since in Italian it's always introduced by *da*, in French it is sometimes introduced by *de* and I had just found out it was introduced by *de* in Medieval Spanish, but your answer has already answered that too.

Answer (score 2):

> suivre du regard, de l'oeil, des yeux = observer, étudier avec soin.

voir http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suivre

c'est une expression liée à ce verbe.

On la rencontre parfois avec certains verbes, avec le sens *avec* : *suivre avec le regard, etc.*

> **montrer** de la main, **signaler** de la main, du regard, **indiquer**,