# How should du regard be understood with the verb parcourait?

Tags: sens

I'm not quite understanding the meaning of *du regard* in the following sentence:

> L'évêque parcourait la salle **du regard** et semblait y faire avec les
> yeux des mesures et des calculs.

It seems to mean something like:

> He roamed through the room **with his eyes**...

But that doesn't fit with how I would normally expect *du regard* to be translated. (I would expect: *of the look*).

**My question:**

Is this a special usage of the phrase *du regard*? What is the correct meaning of it?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/how-to-understand-suivre-des-yeux-syntactically/18973#18973 for other examples of *de* used with this instrumental meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Parcourir du regard* is an expression that means "to look over things", "to browse around".